# Power Query Data from different columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

i am new to Power query and i would like to learn a bit more about it. I am facing the following problem. My table looks like this (empty fields already removed):

[image]

What i'm trying is to get a new table where "Spalte2" holds my list of ISINs and S^"Spalte 8" but also "Spalte 9" and "Spalte 10" hold my portfolio share (komma separated).

EDIT: For clarification I hope to get something like this:

[image]

EDIT: I try to get a table in here, hope it works:

| Spalte1 | Spalte2 | Spalte8 | Spalte9 | Spalte10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bâloise Holding AG | CH0012410517 | 1,04 | Null | Null |
| Barry Callebaut AG | CH0009002962 | 0,63 | Null | Null |
| Galenica AG | CH0360674466 | 0,58 | Null | Null |
| Givaudan SA | CH0010645932 | 1,24 | Null | Null |
| HelloFresh SE | DE000A161408 | 527.705,26 | 1,85 | Null |
| Kering S.A. | FR0000121485 | 431.145,00 | 1,51 | Null |
| Standard Chartered PLC | GB0004082847 | 4,610 117.699,50 | Null | 0,41 |
| Unilever PLC | GB00B10RZP78 | 42,305 315.241,76 | Null | 1,11 |

What i'm trying to get is this:

| Spalte2 | Spalte8 |
| --- | --- |
| CH0012410517 | 1,04 |
| CH0009002962 | 0,63 |
| CH0360674466 | 0,58 |
| CH0010645932 | 1,24 |
| DE000A161408 | 1,85 |
| FR0000121485 | 1,51 |
| GB0004082847 | 0,41 |
| GB00B10RZP78 | 1,11 |

Which way can i use in PQ to match the ISIN with its portfolio share? Thanks a lot!
Thomas

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: Same comment as David. We don't know what you want your output to look like

Comment: Ok, i edited my question, don't know why i got this -1 now. Please let me know if something is still not clear, i appreciate any help, thanks a lot

Comment: I actually didn't downvote, but you have a - because (a) you are making people who want to test something retype your graphic image instead of providing the data as text (2) Is is still very unclear what you are looking to do. You did not adequately the transformation from the input to the output and with the graphic image, its too much manual work to try and figure it out using ctrl-f or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in understanding that you simply want to consolidate the information from the rightmost populated column of each row into one column, and disregard any other information between it and the first column?

If so, then this might be one possible approach.

Starting with a sample table called Table1 in power query:
[image]

I just add a new column and use if then statements to select the rightmost populated column's information:
[image]

(In the above M code, I check that each column is both not null and not blank, to be thorough.)

I get this result:
[image]

Then I select the Spalte2 and Custom columns and remove the other columns to get this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwer. Sorry for posting pics instead of a table but i haven't figured out how to do it.. :-( My problem here is not that some cells are Null but at some point the values that i'm looking fore jump from column 8 to column 9 and later from column 9 to column 10..

Comment: I will try your suggested solution and post an update :-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi, here's the promised update: Yes, it worked, thanks!